# Connection problem with Clickhouse and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, clickhouse

I am a newbie to `Clickhouse` and `RabbitMQ`. While I am trying to record data in `RabbitMQ` to `Clickhouse` with the below script, it doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE Station (
    Station varchar(2000)
  ) ENGINE = RabbitMQ SETTINGS rabbitmq_host_port = '<IP>:5672',
                            rabbitmq_exchange_name = 'Clickhouse',
                            rabbitmq_exchange_type = 'direct',
                            rabbitmq_routing_key_list = 'Station',
                            rabbitmq_format = 'CSV',
                            rabbitmq_num_consumers = 1;
```

And the following error message is given.

```
SQL Error [115]: ClickHouse exception, code: 115, host: <IP>, port: 8123; Code: 115, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Unknown setting rabbitmq_username: for storage RabbitMQ (version 21.4.3.21 (official build))
```

Any suggestion for setting the rabbitmq_username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Rabbit MQ credentials](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/rabbitmq/) should be defined in config-file:

1. open exist or create a new custom config file *rabbitmq.xml*

```sh
sudo nano /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/rabbitmq.xml
```

2. add this configuration & save it

```xml
<yandex>
    <rabbitmq>
        <username>your_rabbitmq_username</username>
        <password>your_rabbitmq_password</password>
    </rabbitmq>
</yandex>
```

3. restart service

```sh
sudo service clickhouse-server restart
```